# Can't convert FITS data (FITS_rec type) to multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing, fits

I am attempting to read in a FITS file and convert the data into a multidimensional numpy array (So i can easily index the data).

The FITS data is structured like:

```
FITS_rec([(time, [rate, rate,  rate,  rate], [ERROR, ERROR, ERROR, ERROR], TOTCOUNTS, fraxexp.)]
```

that is one 'row' (IE = `data[0]` of `data = hdul[1].data`), in my case the number of 'rate' (or error) is varies, for different FITS files.

I wish to make this data into a numpy array, but when I do:
`arr = np.asarray(data)`, I get a 1D object out which I cannot index easily. IE `arr[:][0]` is just equal to `data[0]`.  I have also tried to do a `np.split` with no benifit.

Comment: *"I get a 1D object..."* What is `arr.dtype`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser

 'arr.dtype' is a 'np.record':

The full return is
dtype((numpy.record, [('TIME', '>f8'), ('RATE', '>f8', (4,)), ('ERROR', '>f8', (4,)), ('TOTCOUNTS', '>i4'), ('FRACEXP', '>f8')])

Comment: This is a FITS table and it's represented as a souped up [NumPy structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html).  So you can access individual columns like `data['TIME']`.